# Can I set a Sass variable inside a breakpoint?

Tags: sass, breakpoint-sass

Is it possible to set the value of a variable once, inside a single sass-breakpoint, rather than each time I use the variable?

In other words, I'd like to do this:

```
$tab: 600px;
$wp: 100%;

@include breakpoint($tab) {
    $wp: 95%;
}

.alpha {
    // ...
    width: $wp;
}

.beta {
    // ...
    width: $wp;
}

.gamma {
    // ...
    width: $wp;
}
```

... rather than this:

```
$tab: 600px;
$wp: 100%;
$wp-tab: 95%;

.alpha {
    // ...
    width: $wp;
    @include breakpoint($tab) {
        width: $wp-tab;
    }
}

.beta {
    // ...
    width: $wp;
    @include breakpoint($tab) {
        width: $wp-tab;
    }
}

.gamma {
    // ...
    width: $wp;
    @include breakpoint($tab) {
        width: $wp-tab;
    }
}
```

I don't think the first approach will work as is. Is there another way to achieve the same result? Is this approach a bad idea?

Comment: Have you tried the first way? I think it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is not possible.

Quoting **nex3**, the developer of Sass:

> While this would be pretty cool, it's very much contrary to the
>   existing semantics of a Sass stylesheet. What you've outlined already
>   has a meaning: it sets the variable twice in sequence and then
>   accesses it (modulo some scoping issues). The sequential and largely
>   imperative nature of Sass means that the sort of automatic duplication
>   of rules you're describing becomes very complex. We actually
>   considered something very similar for handling SassScript &, and ended
>   up realizing that it was effectively impossible to do so and preserve
>   the existing semantics.
>
> The best approximation you can do right now is to put the styles that
>   need to vary in a mixin with parameters and include that in your media
>   queries.

Source: https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/1227

Comment: Why couldn't I find that? Thanks.